# Unicode flags is ok on Firefox but two letters in Chromium; for example 

Tags: unicode, chromium, emoji

Can I fix it? I see that even in devtools (the version is 77) the pictures are missing:
[image: chromium devtools dark unicode flags emoji]
While in Firefox 69 on Linux [image: firefox devtools dark inicode flags emoji belgium usa]

I tried all system `font-family` in Chromium with no luck. Page for check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Firefox ships with a built-in font.

[image]

Simply install a font that contains the glyphs for the flags system-wide so that it becomes available to any application.

Comment: same reason as [How do these icons work: ✅️?](https://superuser.com/a/1173928/241386) where the emojis are displayed with color in Firefox but not Chrome